# A label not coloring itself when clicking a button

Tags: lazarus

I was programming 2 buttons which should change the color of the label with a button click. The code worked for me in school, but it does not seem to work at home.

```pascal
unit Unit1;

{$mode objfpc}{$H+}

interface

uses
  Classes, SysUtils, Forms, Controls, Graphics, Dialogs, StdCtrls;

type

  { TForm1 }

  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    Button1: TButton;
    Button2: TButton;
    Label1: TLabel;
    Label2: TLabel;

    procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
    procedure Button2Click(Sender: TObject);

    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
    procedure Label2Click(Sender: TObject);

  private

  public

  end;

  TAmpel = class(TObject)
    farbe: integer;           //1: rot; 2: gelb; 3: grün
    AmpelLabel: TLabel;       // Referenz auf das zugehörige TLabel-Objekt
    constructor Create(ALabel: TLabel);
    procedure schalten();
  private
  public
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;
  VAmpel1: TAmpel;
  VAmpel2: TAmpel;

implementation

{$R *.lfm}

{ TForm1 }

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  VAmpel1 := TAmpel.Create(Label1);
  VAmpel1.farbe := 1;

  VAmpel2 := TAmpel.Create(Label2);
  VAmpel2.farbe := 1;
end;

procedure TForm1.Label2Click(Sender: TObject);
begin

end;

{ TAmpel }

constructor TAmpel.Create(ALabel: TLabel);
begin
  inherited Create;
  AmpelLabel := ALabel;
end;

procedure TAmpel.schalten();
begin
  if farbe = 1 then
  begin
    AmpelLabel.Color := clRed;
    farbe := 2;
  end
  else if farbe = 2 then
  begin
    AmpelLabel.Color := clLime;
    farbe := 3;
  end
  else if farbe = 3 then
  begin
    AmpelLabel.Color := clYellow;
    farbe := 1;
  end;
end;

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  VAmpel1.schalten();
end;

procedure TForm1.Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  VAmpel2.schalten();
end;

end.
```

I am clicking on the button, but the label is not changing its color.

What's the reason?

Comment: hi, what version of lazarus do you use? I tried to recreated your application and the color of the label gets red after I click on a button. If you write  `Label1.Color := clRed;` on buttonClick - does it get red ?

Comment: Which files did you take with you from your school. Probably the link/connection between your form components and your code is broken. If you create the project anew in your home, it will work.